# Is there a way to display Y-axis in log scale in Billboard.js?

Tags: billboard.js

I am trying to display data in log scale to ensure that smaller values are seen when large values are present.  Is there a way to do this in Billboard.js?  It would be great if you can automatically go between linear and logscale depending on data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option for log scales, but you can make visualize as is.
Checkout the follow example.

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
 data: {
  columns: [
   ["data1", 1, 10, 20, 30, 40]
  ]
 },
 clipPath: false,
 axis: {
  y: {
   min: 1,
   tick: {
    values: [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    format: function(x) {
     var value = x > 1 ? Math.pow(10, x/10) : x;

     return Number(value.toFixed(2));
    }
   },
   padding: {
    bottom: 0
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <title>billboar.js - log scale</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```